# How to Configure PhPStorm for the MVC Pattern

Tags: phpstorm

How do I configure PHPStorm so I stop getting warnings about not being able to resolve Directories in Links that are to controller/functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DiscontentDisciple Figured it out, Updating for Others:

Code > Configure Current File Analysis > Configure Inspections > HTML > Uncheck Unknown Href Target.